# Can I use the Entity Data Model to create DDL mapping to existing classes?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-4.5, ddl

I have an XSD for objects which (with one exception) are simply a collection of simple properties (string, int, datetime) and therefore map directly to DB tables we want to create. I've already auto-created C# classes using XSD.exe.

When we receive XML for a web-service I deserialize it to a collection of these C# objects. I would then also like to do a dump of each object to a DB table, where the fields map 1:1 to the C#/XSD objects.

I see there are a few tools which try to generate DDL from XSD or C# but I wondered if the newer Entity Data Model stuff can do this within Visual Studio directly?

I am happy the generated DDL is only a starting point for me to tinker with, not a polished final product. Is this in scope for the EDM or have I misunderstood what that technology is for?

I'm using .NET 4.5 and SQLServer.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted  (and then removed a comment) which gave me the information I needed...

**Yes, it can. You want to look up "Entity Framework Code First".**

Her is an introduction: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx